# MongoDB: how to find documents of same type with min value

Tags: mongodb

I have the following docs in collection:

```
{'type': 1, 'price': 150}
{'type': 1, 'price': 90}
{'type': 2, 'price': 150}
{'type': 2, 'price': 90}
```

How could i find a doc of each type with min price?

i need to query and get:

```
{'type': 1, 'price': 90}
{'type': 2, 'price': 90}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      price: { $min: "$price" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      price: 1,
      type: "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZqZnGpNKIs_)